# How to dynamically generate select elements with different models?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` where I generate new `select` elements on a page. It works fine, they are created together with all the options. The problem is that they end up having the same `ng-model` and thus if there is more than one `select` on the page, only the first one gets the default selected value and changing the selected item is causing the selected items in the other select to be unselected.

Basically, I have the following code for generating them:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-if="item.type === 'select'">
        <select ng-init="data.selectedItem = data.selectedItem || item.subItems[0]"
                class="form-control"
                ng-model="data.selectedItem"
                ng-change="selectedItemChanged()" 
                ng-options="subItem as subItem.name for subItem in item.subItems">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data looks like this:

```
scope.items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        type: 'select',
        subItems: [{
            ID: 1,
            name: 'sub item 1'
        }, {
            ID: 2,
            name: 'sub item 2'
        }, {
            ID: 3,
            name: 'sub item 3'
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: 'select',
        subItems: [{
            ID: 4,
            name: 'sub item 4'
        }, {
            ID: 5,
            name: 'sub item 5'
        }, {
            ID: 6,
            name: 'sub item 6'
        }]
    },
    ];
```

I have tried the following way of assigning different (dynamic) models to each select:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-if="item.type === 'select'">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
            <select ng-init="data[data.selectedItem + item.id] = data[data.selectedItem + item.id] || data[item.subItems[0] + item.id]"
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-model="data[data.selectedItem + item.id]"
                    ng-change="selectedItemChanged(data[data.selectedItem + item.id])" 
                    ng-options="subItem as subItem.name for subItem in item.subItems">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now the problem is that it doesn't set the default item in the select when the page loads for first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach to use two different models is correct.

- Bind the `item.subItems[0].name` as default value if `selectedItem` for the dropdown does not exist.
- Also in `ng-options`, `subItem.name` should be the value rather than `subItem` which is the entire object.

  `ng-options="subItem.name as subItem.name for subItem in item.subItems"`

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) { 
  
  $scope.items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        type: 'select',
        subItems: [{
            ID: 1,
            name: 'sub item 1'
        }, {
            ID: 2,
            name: 'sub item 2'
        }, {
            ID: 3,
            name: 'sub item 3'
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: 'select',
        subItems: [{
            ID: 4,
            name: 'sub item 4'
        }, {
            ID: 5,
            name: 'sub item 5'
        }, {
            ID: 6,
            name: 'sub item 6'
        }]
    },
    ];
 
    $scope.data = {selectedItem1 : '', selectedItem2 : ''};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-if="item.type === 'select'">
        <select ng-init="data['selectedItem' + item.id] = data['selectedItem' + item.id] || item.subItems[0].name"
                class="form-control"
                ng-model="data['selectedItem' + item.id]"
                ng-change="selectedItemChanged()" 
                ng-options="subItem.name as subItem.name for subItem in item.subItems">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
  {{data | json}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine! I only ended up using the whole `subItem` object in `ng-options` because that way the model has the whole object rather than just the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
.... changing the selected item is causing the selected items in the other select to be unselected
```

What u r facing here is scope pollution in angular

u can choose to make a custom directive and set the scope as isolated-scope using `scope:{}`
If u r using a bindToController syntax, then it will be:

```
scope:{},
bindToController:{}
```

angular.directive('selectBox', selectBox);

```
function selectBox(){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {},
   template: `
   //whatever ur html code + ng-model + other ng- directives goes here.
       `, 
//notice its backticks, backticks allow multiline strings in es6 and 
//is supported in most browsers.
   //anyother properties like replace/transclude+ng-transclude, etc.
  } //return ends
} //selectBox ends
```

in HTML:

```
<select-box></select-box>
<select-box></select-box>
<select-box></select-box>
```

and now if u change anything, the other select-dropdowns will not be affected as each of them have their own scope.

PS: so many ng-directives r in ur control, all of them will kick of the digest cycle and as ur page grows, it will become slower. "debounce", wherever possible.